# SharePoint 2010 Document Save As Dialog Preventing Other Locations

Tags: document-library, word

I have a SharePoint 2010 Document Library in which multiple content types have been added in the New Document Menu. Now, when a user clicks on any of these items, it will open locally installed Word with an empty document based on that Content Type (template).

Now when the user presses Save, in the Save Dialog, the Document Library from where the user came from is displayed, but the users can still go ahead and select any other locations such as their My Documents or Desktop on the left navigation pane in the Save As Dialog.

The requirement is to restrict that the users saving only into that SharePoint location. How do we prevent them from selecting any of the other locations in the Save As Dialog

Comment: I believe Anders is right.  Not allowing someone to save a local copy of the template/file to work on offline is poor design.  Coding up a solution to eliminate that option is a waste of time and resources in my opinion, requirement or not.  It's a burden on the users.

Comment: Actually, the requirement is to stop them from saving word into local areas only when they have come from the "New Document" menu in a SP Document Library, not when they use Word independently.

Comment: Yes, I knew that's what you were talking about.  It's still a poor requirement from an end user perspective.

Comment: I agree :(, any Word Add-In, that could do this, you think?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this isnt possible OOB in word. I would recommend asking in a forum more orientated to word / VSTO developer fora on how to achieve this.

Word development 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905482.aspx

word answers:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/word

Answer (score 0):

Use the BeforeSave event, add your own event handler. In the event handler, cancel the save dialog by setting `EventArgs.Cancel = true` and `EventArgs.ShowSaveAsDialog = false`. Then use a custom save dialog of your creation instead which enforces your save location. It shouldn't be that hard to create a dialog, and saving the document you can do with lots of examples on the web.